# How to get nested collection change event to bubble up

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a series of nested collections that I need to detect a change anywhere from the uppermost to lowermost layer. First, I'll show my code:

```
public class CategoricalDataItem
{
    public string XValue { get; set; }

    public double YValue { get; set; }

    public SolidColorBrush Color { get; set; }

    public CategoricalDataItemCollection SimpleSubData { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class CategoricalDataItemCollection : ObservableCollection<CategoricalDataItem>
{
    public string Descriptor { get; set; }
}
```

This code is structured for drill-down charting. Basically, I am allowing 5 layers deep. A developer could create an instance of CategoricalDataItemCollection and for each CategoricalDataItem within that collection, a new instance of CategoricalDataItemCollection could be created and so on. I am needed to be made aware if any item is added or removed from any of these nested collections. CollectionChanged event only detects a change in the first layer. Suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is monitoring the collection for changes. Below is an example for doing so.

I included a small test class that will spit out messages as new items are added.

The key thing to note is that you are essentially consuming your own inherited `CollectionChanged` event so that you can monitor the children coming in and out and listening for when their collection changes. Please pay special attention that this is purely an example and needs some polishing and testing when it comes to the `MyCollectionChanged(...)` as there are other `NotifyCollectionChangedAction`s that need to be handled.

```
[Serializable]
public class CategoricalDataItemCollection : ObservableCollection<CategoricalDataItem>
{
    public string Descriptor { get; set; }

    public CategoricalDataItemCollection()
    {
        this.CollectionChanged += MyCollectionChanged;
    }

    void MyCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        // There are other actions to handle. This is purely an example.
        if (args.OldItems != null)
        {
            foreach (var oldItem in args.OldItems.Cast<CategoricalDataItem>())
            {
                if (args.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
                    oldItem.SimpleSubData.CollectionChanged -= InvokeCollectionChanged;
            }
        }

        if (args.NewItems != null)
        {
            foreach (var newItem in args.NewItems.Cast<CategoricalDataItem>())
            {
                if (args.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
                    newItem.SimpleSubData.CollectionChanged += InvokeCollectionChanged;
            }
        }
    }

    void InvokeCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        // This is the tricky part. Nothing actually changed in our collection, but we
        // have to signify that something did.
        OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }
}

public class TestClass
{
    public void TestNotify()
    {
        var parent = new CategoricalDataItemCollection();
        parent.CollectionChanged += (sender, args) => Debug.Print("Parent Collection Changed");

        var child = new CategoricalDataItem {SimpleSubData = new CategoricalDataItemCollection()};
        child.SimpleSubData.CollectionChanged += (sender, args) => Debug.Print("Child Collection Changed");

        var grandChild = new CategoricalDataItem { SimpleSubData = new CategoricalDataItemCollection()};
        grandChild.SimpleSubData.CollectionChanged += (sender, args) => Debug.Print("Grand Child Collection Changed");

        //Should only output "Parent"
        parent.Add(child);

        //Should only output "Child" and then "Parent"
        child.SimpleSubData.Add(grandChild);

        //Should now output "Grand Child" and then "Child" and then "Parent" messages.
        grandChild.SimpleSubData.Add(new CategoricalDataItem(){SimpleSubData = new CategoricalDataItemCollection()});
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm terrible with events so please excuse my ignorance. The uppermost layer is actually CategoricalDataItemCollection not CategoricalDataItem. So do I need to repeat this methodology in the CategoricalDataItemCollection class so I can subscribe to that event in my calling class?

Comment: @flyNflip I have updated my answer to have the collection do the monitoring. Good luck!

Comment: I wanted to say thanks again for your help. I spent quite a while studying events, breaking down your code, and applying different variants to solve my particular problem. Ultimately, the problem was that I didn't have simple nested collections. Instead of having Collection > Collection > Collection > ... I have Collection > Item > Collection > Item > ... This was the hard part. Had it been simple nested collections, bubbling up the events wouldn't be that bad. I did end up going a different route to solve my problem but your answer is a viable solution with a little tweaking. Thank You

Comment: @flyNflip No prob. Glad you were able to work through your issue and actually identify a better way to go.